# Questions on CDARs

Tags: united-states, investing

I was investigating a CDAR as a possibility for a large sum investment. However, I was under a false impression that I could leave the primary investment aka the principle in the cdar and then have the interest deposited in another account. The idea was to use the principle under a trust to generate capital that could then be distributed to a beneficiary. However, it looks like most CD's aren't set up that way, or if they were, they would be variable rate with lower interest rates. I'm specifically looking to keep the principal there for 20+ years, just have the interest as a monthly distribution. What would be the best course of action?

Comment: What is a CDAR besides a FLA?